# Grunt: When the depended @import target is modified, how to compile the parent depender?

Tags: gruntjs, stylus, codekit

I'm trying to migrate my Stylus compilation process from [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) to Grunt.

Here's how the files are structured:

```
/styl
  - page-1.styl
  - page-2.styl
  - …
  - /components
    - header.styl
    - footer.styl
    - module-1.styl
    - …
```

Each `page-x.styl` in the dir root has `@import` statements that pull module stylesheets from the `./styl/components` subdir.

For example, `page-1.styl` looks like this:

```
 @import 'components/header'
 @import 'components/module-1'

 // Other styles here
 .foo { … }
 …
```

When I modify `components/header.styl`, CodeKit smartly picks up the `@import` relationship and compiles `page-1.styl` (and other files that import the same modified file) accordingly, and even gets bonus points for excluding `components/header.styl` itself from compilation too.

Unsurprisingly, this doesn't happen using `grunt-contrib-watch` + `grunt-contrib-stylus` alone. Has anyone managed to get this working through Grunt?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your Gruntfile.js ? (ie: the one referring to stylus files and watch tasks)

Comment: Sure thing @JeremieParker: https://gist.github.com/thatmarvin/6528950 (it's pretty basic, distilled down to the relevant parts)

Comment: I'm not sure but, in your gist, you have `cwd: 'public/styl'` and `files: ['public/css/**/*.styl']`, which, if I'm not misguided, means that you compile files (specified by `filepath` in the `src` parameter) relative to the former when files from the later are modified. Is that the intended behavior ?

Comment: That's a typo and I've corrected it.